# How to have All text darker (like bold) in all programs for ease of reading

Tags: text, contrast

HP Pavilion Gaming laptop on Windows 10

I am not asking how to make the display brighter.
I am also not asking how to adjust the contrast between colors.

I need to know how to make a change so the text in ALL programs will be darker, i.e., like when I bold text in Word or Outlook.  Then it will be easier for me to read.

I do not want to set High Contrast, because it makes most things Black.  Printing a screen shot would use an enormous amount of ink.  I usually paste into Word to print them.

Also, when I have High Contrast set, open Kindle, and type characters for a search, the characters do not display.  It seems that the characters are being echoed in the same color as the background for the search box – black.

Examples of where I need “darker/bolded” text:  Windows Settings, Firefox with some web pages, Windows Explorer, Outlook 2016 list of emails in a folder.

I should mention that I have some trouble seeing in the dark now, as of a few years ago.

Comment: Is this related to programming?

Comment: No.  It is for readability in all programs.

Comment: I recommend reading this [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as it may provide you with a better StackExchange site to ask similar questions

Comment: Unless it's related to an IDE or a software tool that is commonly used by programmers. Which you have not specified.